# Returned integer using number of value c#

Tags: c#

I have two strings, g1 and g2. I'm randomly determining whether to use g1, or g2, that is, like a cointoss. How do I go about doing something like g + coin(); to output g1, or g2, depending on what coin() returns?

Comment: What have you tried? Does it work? If not, why not? As it is now, this is "Not a real question".

Comment: How have you written the `coin` method?  Add some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just:

```
return (coin() == 'heads' ? g1 : g2);
```

Comment: Here was me busting out a `switch` statement when this popped up! Time for a coffee...

Answer (score 1):

```
string SelectOne(string g1, string g2)
{
    return (new Random().NextDouble() > 0.5) ? g1 : g2;
}
```

Comment: Might consider using an a static Random instance or at least the same instance in the class so that rapid calls to `SelectOne` don't result in the same "Random" value.

Answer (score 0):

Store both in an array:

```
string[] g = { "g1", "g2" };
```

Then, roll a random number:

```
var random = new Random();
int index = random.Next(2);
```

And finally, get the string at that index:

```
string choice = g[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't work with local variable names in C# (though you can work with type member names through reflection).

You can either use plain old `if`:

```
if (coin() == 1)
    result = g1;
else
    result = g2;
```

or you could use an array:

```
var gs = new[] { g1, g2 };
var result = gs[coin() - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
Random rd = new Random();

string strtouse = "g" + (rd.Next(2) + 1);
```

Now u may use the following snippet to

```
string test = (string)this.GetType().GetField(strtouse).GetValue(this);
```

Though this is not a good way to achieve what you want. Using Dictionaries is a better way.